# how to differentiate -is from -es sound sing/plur?

Tags: grammatical-number, pronunciation, latin

Especially in the context of Latin and Latin-derived words, where the English pronunciation is often rather arbitrary, this might lead foreigners to confusion between the singular and plural forms.
I am therefore asking native speakers how the differentiate the two sounds in words like:

- Analysis vs. Analyses
- Anastomosis vs. Anastomoses
- Metamorphosis vs. Metamorphoses

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In words such as these, the pronunciation of both the last vowel and final consonant change: the singular forms end in /-ɪs/ and the plural in /-iːz/ (transcriptions in [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet): /ɪs/ as the "iss" in "kiss", /iːz/ as the "eys" in "keys").